# Intent во Fragment

Tags: java, android

День добрый. Пытаюсь открыть активити из фрагмента

```
Intent intent = new Intent(F.this, Activity.class);
```

F.this, Activity.class подчеркнуто, пишет что такого метода нет. Как можно решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `getActivity()`. В вашем случае:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
```

Так же будьте осторожны с `getActivity()`. Если фрагмент не `attached` или уже `detached` то метод вернет `null`.